# shell script to delete the 3 days old logs from the directory

Tags: shell, unix

As i am working in unix environment so i have an logs that is created by my application at the following location that is

```
/opt/app/glac/current/servers/ops/log
```

inside the log directory there are different kinds of logs(that is the file having extesion as .log ) have been created ,can you please advise i want to write a shell script such that that script will ask the user the number of day such that if user enter the value `3` so in that case it will delete all the logs that are 3 days old , lets say if date is `19 dec 2015` and if user enter the value as 3 then it will delete the logs including of 16 dec also it will only keep the logs of `17,18 and 19 dec` only

please advise what will be the shell script to achieve this

Comment: Log rotation, compression and removal are typically handled using the "logrotate" package. Very convenient, secure and easy to setup. It should be installed on typical unixoid systems these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mtime` in the `find` command.

`#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter no of days :"
read ARCHIVE_DAYS
find /opt/app/glac/current/servers/ops/logs  -name '*.log' -mtime +${ARCHIVE_DAYS}  -type f -exec rm -f {} \;`